# How to show data summary by dotplot/barlpot in Rshiny on hover of cell value

Tags: r, plot, shiny, datatable

I have a datatable in RShiny as shown below.

```
ID  num_express dene    trans   a_dd_s.1    a_de_s.2    a_dd_s.3    a_de_s.4    a_de_s.5    a_dd_s.6    a_dd_s.100
id1 6   .   -1  2   5   0   7   1   2   9
id2 3   .   -1  6   2   0   1   0   0   0
id3 7   .   -1  3   8   6   12  10  12  9
id4 7   .   -1  3   14  4   10  17  22  10
id5 4   .   -1  0   8   0   4   0   4   4
```

The actual data table has >1000 columns. The value in the second column is the number of columns with value >0 in the columns a_dd_s.1 to a_dd_s.100 and b_dd_s.1 to b_dd_s.100.....z_dd_s.1 to z_dd_s.100. The first letter before the delimiter "_" correspond to the group. Here `a,b,c....z` are the groups.

The large number of columns are not flexible to the user to navigate/scroll the datatable. Therefore, i would like to display only columns 1-4 in the data table. And show the numeric data in columns a_dd_s.1 to z_dd_s.100 as a barchart/dotplot colored by group when the value in the second column is clicked or hovered in each row.

Could this be done in Shiny. If so could someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first "onclick" approach using a callback in `dataTable` to extract the row ID we are in and then using this ID within an `observeEvent` statement to `filter` the data and create a plot inside a modal page with `showModal(modalDialog())`.

**Update**
According to the OP's comments I now:

1. used {ggiraph} to add tooltips showing the variable name and value to the plot
2. added variable groups (`a:c`) allowing to color the data points accordingly
3. made the modal page wider by adding `css` (`modalDialog` has a `size` argument, but here `"l"` is still not large enough).
4. made the plot bigger to show the variable names, however, showing them is still pretty messy (there are more than 1000 variables) so I think the better option is to just show the tooltip and the coloring by group.

   ```
      library(shiny)
      library(DT)
      library(data.table)
      library(forcats)
      library(ggplot2)
      library(waiter)
      library(plotly)


      modalActionButton <- function(inputId, label, icon = NULL, width = NULL, ...) {

        value <- restoreInput(id = inputId, default = NULL)
        tags$button(id = inputId, type = "button", style = if (!is.null(width)) 
          paste0("width: ", validateCssUnit(width), ";"), type = "button", 
          class = "btn btn-default action-button", `data-dismiss` = "modal", `data-val` = value, 
          list(shiny:::validateIcon(icon), label), ...)

      }

      # more realistic toy data which mimics your actual data
      # we will transform it later
      dat <- tibble::tribble(
        ~ID,  ~num_express, ~dene,    ~trans,
        "id1", 6,   ".",   -1,
        "id2", 3,   ".",   -1,
        "id3", 7,   ".",   -1,
        "id4", 7,   ".",   -1,
        "id5", 4,   ".",   -1) %>%
        tidyr::expand_grid(group = letters[1:3],
                           no = 1:100) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(var_nm = paste0(group, "_dd_s.", no),
                      var_val = round(runif(1500, min = 0, max = 99), 0)) %>%
        tidyr::pivot_wider(.,
                           id_cols = c(ID, num_express, dene, trans),
                           names_from = var_nm,
                           values_from = var_val)

      dat <- as.data.table(dat)
      # data preparation no using {data.table} starts here
      # before starting the data preparation with your real data
      # save it as .csv and it read in at the start of the app with
      # `dat <- fread("yourdata.csv")` 
      dat_dt <- dat[, -c(2:4), with=FALSE]
      dat_dt <- melt(dat_dt,
                     id.vars = "ID",
                     variable.name = "col_nm",
                     value.name = "val")
      dat_dt[, c("group", "col_nm1", "col_nm2", "col_no") := tstrsplit(col_nm, "[\\._]")
             ][,
               ttip := paste0("var: ", col_nm, "<br>",
                              "value: ", val)
               ][,
                 col_nm := as.factor(col_nm)
                 ]

    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage(
        use_waiter(),

     # make modal page wider
        tags$head(
          tags$style(HTML("

       .modal-dialog {
          width: 80%;
       }
     "))
        ),

        DT::dataTableOutput('table')

      ), # close FluidPage


      server = function(input, output, session) {

        w <- Waiter$new(id = "plot",
                        html = spin_whirly(),
                        color = "#FFFFFF")

        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
          datatable(dat[, .(ID, num_express, dene, trans)],
                    rownames = FALSE,
                    selection = 'none',
                    # get ID of clicked row
                    callback = JS(
                      'table.on("click.dt","tr", function() {
                var data=table.row(this).data();
                Shiny.onInputChange("rows",data[0]);
                 });')
          )
          })

        data_row <- reactive({

          dat_dt[ID == input$rows & val != 0,]

        })

        flag <- reactiveValues(val = 0)

        observeEvent(input$close, {

          flag$val <- flag$val - 1

        })

        observeEvent(input$rows, {

          flag$val <- flag$val + 1

        })

        temp_plot <- reactive({

          w$show()

          if (flag$val == 0) {

            p <- plotly_empty() %>% config(displayModeBar = FALSE,
                                      displaylogo = FALSE)

          } else {

          p <- ggplot(data_row(),
                      aes(x = fct_reorder(col_nm, val, min, .desc = TRUE),
                          y = val,
                          fill = group
                      )) +
            geom_col(position = "dodge") +
            scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.x = element_blank())

          p <- ggplotly(p)

          }

          w$hide()

          p

        })

        output$plot <- renderPlotly({

          print(flag$val)

          temp_plot()

        })

        observeEvent(input$rows, {
          showModal(modalDialog(
            title = paste("Plot:", input$rows),
            plotlyOutput("plot",
                         width = "100%"),
            size = "l",
            easyClose = FALSE,
            footer = modalActionButton("close",
                                       "Close")
          ))
        })


      }
    )
   ```

Comment: It works. However, the x-axis names ("col_name") are clustered and not visible with the actual dataset which has ~1000 columns. Did not work by adding `theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))` to the plot.  1) can the plot size be increased so that x-axis names are visible 2) can the data point in the plot be hovered to see the "col_name" 3) can the dot plot be colored to groups for example by a,b, c if the columns are in the format a.1,a.2,...a.10, b.1, b.2...b.9, c.1...c.10

Comment: @chas: I updated my answer, please have a look. It is still a lot of variables therefore I would prefer to only show the tooltip and the group coloring without showing every single variable name.

Comment: i get the error `Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 635 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].
Warning in f(names[[col]]) : NAs introduced by coercion`. Could this be due to actual column names format which are like a_dd_s.1, a_dd_s.2... where the first letter before first '_' is the group which is 'a' here?

Comment: secondly, to decrease variables, can the variables with value =0 be removed from each row for plotting.  And plot `x = val,y = col_nm` with y-axis names in the descending order by values of `val`? This should solve the need as the dataset is too big for much better visualizations.

Comment: @chas: yes, the error message is from `pivot_longer` probably because of the different col names. I will look into that with your updated question. Filtering and ordering the variables is no problem, I will post an update later.

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend any better visualizations than this? the idea is to see immediately which variable has highest value and to which group it belongs to. And the variables could be across 80 groups in the maximum scenario and at the least scenario only within one group.

Comment: The question is: (1) do you want to get an overview to see how all variables and groups compare, or (2) do you just want to know the one, two variables with the highest value and their name and group. A plot like the one above will be a good solution for (1) while a different approach for (2) would be to write the highest variable name and value in a separate column and to show this column in your datatable.

Comment: need to get an overview of all variables and corresponding groups. so it is (1)

Comment: @chas: I updated my answer. Please have a look. Even with you new column names I could reproduce the error. Let me know if the error still persists.

Comment: With the above code, the data and the app  gets loaded after ~45min. The `dat_long` is taking  very long time >45min to execute on real data. Probably `dat_long` should be saved as an Rdata file and use everytime. Could this be done here? However, there is no error this time but i get an empty modal page with only title text and no plot. Also, i tried to put the data preparation code under `dat_long`  in the server side inside `renderGirafe` function and in this case I do get the same error as before.

Comment: Given the size of your data it is better the use {data.table} for the processing. I change my code. It should be much faster with your real data. Please try saving your data as csv and read it in with `csv`, see my inline comments. The data preparation should not be placed in the the `renderGirafe` function, since we only need it to run once the app starts. You can also do the data processing and save the result too as csv and then just read in two csv files. Are you working with two separate scripts one for UI and one for server?

Comment: Yes, i do have separate scripts for ui and server. Now i have saved the processed data into a csv file and read two files, one for data table and the other for ggplot. It works now, shows the plot as required. However, there is lag to show the modal page and display the plot. Probably it is taking time to filter the data by row. This makes it confused whether the click on the row has suceeded or not. May b if the lag cannot be eliminated, could we show some progress or status until the modal page and plot appears?

Comment: @chas: I, too, noticed the lag when the new plot renders. I now added a loading screen (spinner) via the {waiter} package.

Comment: Unfortunately, the spinner isn;t working. could you please check

Comment: Strange, it was working fine here. I was using {waiter} version 1.0. Now I updated to version 1.3 from CRAN and it is not working anymore.

Comment: in the above code and the toy data, i never see the spinner as the plots corresponding to the row are immediately displayed on click.  Whereas with the actual data, the modal page pops up as usual with the lag (1-2min) i.e. not immediately when the row is clicked. After that the plot is shown only for a fraction of a second, the plot disappears and then the spinner spins all the time. this turns out to be a major problem now than the actual problem :)

Comment: @chas: I now replaced the waiter functions with `waiter_on_busy()`. Does this work better with you original data?

Comment: i thank for your valuable time. 1) The spinner is now showing up in all pages of the application, i.e. when switching the tab pages etc.. but it is required to be loaded only for this page which we are working when the row click is made in the data table. 2) what could be the rate limiting step here as the time taken to display plot from one row click to the other is quiet long.

Comment: probably i should have mentioned earlier that this page is part of the application which is in one of the tabs of the app. though the `use_waiter` is put within the ui code of this page it is shown in all the other pages and also for the app when the app is loading initially.

Comment: @chas: In this case it is better to not use `waiter_on_busy()`. Ideally, you can comment the original {waiter} calls back in (they are still in the code) and it should work, at least the example above works. If it does not work, you might try to download the [development version of waiter on GitHub](https://github.com/JohnCoene/waiter).

Comment: It works. Thanks. I have accepted the answer. Still, As you have suggested, i have prepared the data and also removed the zero count variables and saved as csv file. This file is read when the app is loaded. HOwever, upon clicking the row, the spinner spins for 1-2min and then the plot is displayed. Though we have loaded the processed data, the lag while displaying the plot couldn't be elimnated. Is it the `ggplot` function where the delay is caused? could we somehow reduce the lag and speedup?

Comment: I think the lag comes from rendering the graphic. I updated the code to make a few changes. First I tried using {plotly}'s `ggplotly`. This might speed up the rendering time (maybe it is worth to build the plot without {ggplot2} using plotly only). Then I have an `actionModalButton` which closes the modal page and triggers a blank plotly graphic so we do not see the old plot for 1-2 seconds anymore. This should work nicely with the spinner. Hope it helps.

Comment: it gives the error: `Error in temp$plot <- reactive({ : object 'temp' not found`

Comment: just saying, same row cannot be clicked for the second time consecutively. It has to be clicked on a differrent row and get back to the old row.